# Printing Clone of HTML DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, html2canvas

I want to be able to design a 'flyer' type HTML page, with a specific set height and width, and be able to print it out on a sheet of paper. I'm using normal Letter paper, and have it's dimensions set to a `div`. Though, after printing in the browser, with the `div` having a set background color, nothing shows up in the print popup, as it thinks it is blank. I'm also afraid that printing will mess with the CSS if I style certain text. How can I perfectly clone the `div` to print like with [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="height:1054px;width:816px;background-color:red;position:absolute;top:0;left:0">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Printing the background is an option left to the user, since printing that background is often, from the user's point of view, a waste of (very, very expensive) ink. If the background is required, notify the user that they'll have to tick a box somewhere in the print-settings of either their browser, or computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there is a way to say you want to print something, using `@media print`. But the real magic is the "`webkit-print-color-adjust`" to say: "print the background!" :)

```
@media print {
    div {
        background-color: #red !important;
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is some padding on each side, even when selecting 'Actual size' in the print popup. Is there any way where I can stretch it to the ends of the paper?

Comment: I think this is causing by the default padding and margin, try using:
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

Comment: There is still some margin at the edges. The paper is centered, though.

Comment: Duh, don't forget to set Margin to NONE in the print settings themselves. Thanks for the help.